# Is a nongreedy pattern part of Perl 6's longest token matching?

Tags: regex, raku

I'm playing with this longest token match in 2018.04 but I don't think the longest token is matching:

```
say 'aaaaaaaaa' ~~ m/
    | a+?
    | a+
    /; # ｢a｣
```

I expected the second alternative to have the longest token because it has a greedy quantifier. It looks like the non-greedy quantifier was counted as part of the longest token although [Synopsis 5](https://design.perl6.org/S05.html#Longest-token_matching) indicates that it shouldn't be included.

If I reverse the order I get the output that I expect:

```
say 'aaaaaaaaa' ~~ m/
    | a+
    | a+?
    /;  # ｢aaaaaaaaa｣
```

Is this supposed to happen like this? What does the engine think the length of these tokens are? The official docs are quite vague so I'm drawing on [Synopsis 5](https://design.perl6.org/S05.html#Longest-token_matching) to suss out how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went for a dig in the compiler to see what's happening there. The `+` quantifier action method [calls backmod](https://github.com/perl6/nqp/blob/6c450557d4177ad52b57945e60b45553d1625dd3/src/QRegex/P6Regex/Actions.nqp#L152) which in turn [sets the backtrack property to "f"](https://github.com/perl6/nqp/blob/6c450557d4177ad52b57945e60b45553d1625dd3/src/QRegex/P6Regex/Actions.nqp#L796).

However, the [code to compile an NFA for a quantifier](https://github.com/perl6/nqp/blob/6c450557d4177ad52b57945e60b45553d1625dd3/src/QRegex/NFA.nqp#L404) doesn't look at the backtrack property at all, and is thus treating every quantifier the same, regardless of its backtrack mode. Thus it acts as if the `?` were not there, meaning it will consider the two branches of equal length. It then uses declaration order as a tie-breaker, leading to it picking the first branch. That then applies the frugal quantifier once selected, and so matches a single "a". (This also explains why swapping the order changes things.)

This does seem out of line with what [S05 envisions](https://design.perl6.org/S05.html#Longest-token_matching), which would be that the `a+?` should simply be considered "fate" (in this case meaning the `a+?` alternative would have a zero-length longest token). The specification (that is, test suite specifying the language) is silent on the matter, however, making it undefined behavior at present.

The proposed behavior in S05 makes sense to me, so I'd argue for specifying and implementing it that way. I've opened [this issue](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1924) to track it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the current behavior is correct.

Only things which can be matched by an NFA or a DFA can be part of a Longest-Token Match, and to the best of my knowledge, frugal quantifiers do not translate into the automaton formalism (which works by feeding all characters into the automaton, and has no concept of accepting before the full string has been read).

Comment: How can that behavior be correct if frugal quantified can’t be included?

Comment: Right, so `a+` is a pattern for which the declarative token prefix is the entire pattern, and `a+?` is a pattern for which `a+` is the declarative token prefix (and the `?` is not), so the patterns have the same length declarative token prefixes. So there's a tie, and, quoting from brian's linked design doc, "the tie is broken first by specificity ... longest fixed string wins [but they have the same `a` fixed string] ... If that doesn't work ... If the alternatives are in the same grammar file [they aren't in a grammar but whatever] the textually earlier alternative takes precedence."

Comment: I think you're misreading the synopsis. It says "The constructs deemed to terminate a token declaration and start the "action" part of the pattern include:" then lists "Any atom that is quantified with a frugal match (using the ? modifier)." I think a plain english reading of that means that it's the thing that is quantified, not the quantifier, that is excluded from longest token. I don't see how we can accept any guess that says the ? would silently be discarded from the pattern.

Comment: @briandfoy Yep. I was actually *thinking* "well how does that work then?" which became "Right, so according to the design doc it's this, then that, then, the other?" -- but I forgot the all important question mark. (I hadn't made up my mind quite how to phrase what I was saying, then got a longish phone call, then returned and thought, heck, I'll just post what I've got and see if Moritz agrees.) And I had misread the synopsis. Not that they're spec anyway. And now I see jnthn's answer. I'll leave my comment here to remind folk to add a ? to stuff I write because I always have one in my head.